# C++ wrapper for SQLite3 API - alternatives for sqlite3pp

Tags: c++, sql, sqlite, wrapper

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a good OO C++ wrapper for sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/q/818155/3168107)

I'm looking for C++ wrappers for SQLite3 API. So far, I only found [sqlite3pp](http://code.google.com/p/sqlite3pp/). It seems quite up-to-date, however, before settling with that I wanted to see if there are any alternatives. Do you guys know any? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question, while outdated, was marked as a duplicate, but the original question linked to above has been removed. Probably should be updated, though I'm not sure the protocol / procedure for that.

Comment: Link replaced with a live one...

Comment: The replacement link has a completely different question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know why I can't find the Wiki linked from the SQLite homepage anymore. But it lists lots of C++ wrappers: http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=SqliteWrappers