# Crossplatform Sqlite3 Wrapper for C++

Tags: c++, sqlite

I am looking for a crossplatform Sqlite wrapper for Sqlite3.
Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120295/what-is-a-good-oo-c-wrapper-for-sqlite

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a good OO C++ wrapper for sqlite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120295/what-is-a-good-oo-c-wrapper-for-sqlite)

Comment: no longer a duplicate.  the question was deleted.

Answer (score 2):

QT includes one, wxWidgets includes one.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=SqliteWrappers .

Answer (score 1):

The [SOCI](http://soci.sourceforge.net/index.html) project has a [SQLite3 backend wrapper](http://soci.sourceforge.net/doc/backends/sqlite3.html).

Answer (score 1):

Libgda ( http://www.gnome-db.org ) has some C++ bindings.

Answer (score 0):

[CppSqlite](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CppSQLite.aspx) is a very good C++ wrapper for SQLite. I've used it on *nix and windows without problems.