# XML<->SQLite Data Conversion C++ Linux

Tags: c++, xml, sqlite

I have to convert XML data to SQLite then run some query on that SQLite Data and convert the query results back to XML.  Do we have any C++ library for this.  I am using Linux Operating System.

Regards,
Dinesh.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387610/what-xml-parser-should-i-use-in-c

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120295/what-is-a-good-oo-c-wrapper-for-sqlite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of one library doing all that, and if so it would be horribly complicated. I'm pretty sure you'll need to use two different libraries: One to do the XML parsing/writing and another to do the SQL transactions. You'd have a better design this way - **separation of concerns**.

libxml and libsqlite are two examples which are probably quickly installable in your current distribution. e.g. `sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev libxml2-dev`

Then you'll probably want to:

1. Open the xml, parse into C++ objects and store in a container e.g. std::vector, close the xml.
2. Open a new sqlite database, create a table maybe more, iterate your C++ container of objects inserting values into the table as you iterate;
3. Execute a select query on the new table and read the resultset, for each result storing/editing C++ objects;
4. Create a new xml root object, iterate the new/modified C++ objects and for each object add a new xml node to the root, write the xml tree to a new file.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried libxml++?
http://developer.gnome.org/libxml++-tutorial/stable/